# Asp.net core 2.0 react.js cookie authentication isomorphic-fetch endless loop

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, isomorphic-fetch-api

I have a small asp.net core app with react.js that authenticates users using cookie authentication.
It seems cookie authentication works fine when I directly call controller's action.

For instance if I type http://localhost/Test/Index it works as expected. Authentication is made and cookie is created and in the latter requests it uses cookie.

However when my react component calls a controller method using isomorphic-fetch
it turns to endless authentication loop.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()

    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(19);
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
                });
```

Here is where I authenticate user.(AccountController/Login)

```
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,userName),
            new Claim("AccessToken", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token.AccessToken))
        };

        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(  
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,  
            principal,new AuthenticationProperties{ IsPersistent=true});  

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Here is my fetch method that creates endless login loop.

```
export class ProposalGrid extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchDataExampleState> {
    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
        super(props);
        this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { proposalDatas: [], loading: true, dataState: { take: 10, skip: 0 } };
        let url = "ProposalData/GetProposals?" + $.param({ take: 10, skip: 0 })

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ProposalData[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ proposalDatas: data, loading: false });
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I included credentials when fetching data and change method to post.Problem was disappeared.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
```